# Reducing space after a result of a command

Tags: macros, spacing

I've got a command defined like this:

```
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{abca}{}
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{abcb}{}
}
```

And later in my document I use it like this:

```
\abc{a}, following text
```

How can I reduce the space after the result of that command:

```
abca , following text
```

Thanks in advance for any piece of advice.

Comment: Side note: `ifthen` package is obsoleted, so in new code is better to use `etoolbox`'s `\ifstrequal` or other nice commands defined there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Each end of line counts as a space (if not following a command name)

```
\newcommand{\abc}[1]{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{a}}{abca}{}%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{b}}{abcb}{}%
}
```

One has always to be careful for spaces in definitions that typeset text.